# Markdown: prevent paragraph tag being wrapped around standard HTML span tag

Tags: markdown, html, word-wrap

I want to mix standard HTML and Markdown. 
I have a paragraph written with Markdown, followed by an HTML `<span>` element.

The problem is: if I don't put return after the paragraph: 
the `<span>` will be immediately after the text within the paragraph's `<p>` tag:

```
<p>Some text  
<span>My span</span>  
</p>
```

However if I do put return after the paragraph (written in Markdown), the `<span>` alone will be wrapped around in `<p>` tags, like so:

```
<p>Some text</p>  
<p><span>My span</span></p>
```

What I want is simply this:

```
<p>Some text</p><span>My span</span>
```

Sorry if I am overlooking something very obvious, I'm very tired.
Thanks!

(I'm using Kramdown for conversion if that's any help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I've figured it out! :) So, in Kramdown, you can use some kind of an escape, that prevent parsing what's inside, but you have to be careful to leave blank lines both before and after:

```
<p>Some text</p>  
return  
{::nomarkdown}  
<span>My Span</span>  
{:/}  
return  
...
```

Comment: This solved my problem! Thank you! This Kramdown docs on `nomarkdown` is at the [very bottom of the syntax page](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#extensions) - it's a bit difficult to find. Thanks for not being a DenverCoder9! I really appreciated this fix.

Comment: Glad it helped @JamesLowrey :)